# How to the 'Open image in new tab' url with apex?

Tags: images

I have a chart[image]

when u right click on i can select 'Open image in new tab' as per the picture.

The URL that shows is something like this 
'https://cs5.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.ChartServer?rsid=0FLO0000000D9cl&ruid=00590000001gonj&did=01Z90000000Aeq6&s=7&fs=10&tfg=12&tfs=-16777216&explode=0&c=gauge&cs=0&title=T2C+Won+YTD&eh=no&compo=no&fg=-16777216&bg1=-1&bg2=-1&bgdir=2&dl1=Stage&dl2=&l=2&sax=yes&Yman=no&nc=0&actUrl=%2F00O90000007kgqp%3Fdbw%3D1&sd=1&scv=no&sct=yes&spt=no&bd=yes&cu=AUD&ab=X&u=0&vt=0&ab2=Y&u2=1&vt2=0&vl0=GWH&spoc=no&topn=no&gm=0.0&gc0=-4041644&gm0=150.0&gc1=-4013484&gm1=172.0&gc2=-11222444&gm2=195.0&sona=0&refreshts=1468870082000'

My question is when I click on this and see the image by itself in the new tab, can i obtain the URL that it is showing using Apex/VF somehow, ie: 
Can i obtain the URL that would show if the image was opened manually?

SO i don't want to open the image and obtain the URL. I want a program to access, derive etc the URL 'as if' it had been opened manually in a browser.

I then need that URL to be put into a text field.

cheers.